Как задать начальную страницу для браузерной версии кроссплатформенном приложении Avalonia UI?
Я пишу кроссплатформенное приложение на Avalonia UI с использованием Community Toolkit.
Все работает и на Windows и на Android эмуляторе, но когда я хочу запустить версию приложения для браузера, то там просто выводится стандартная надпись "Powered by Avalonia", которая прописана в index.html и app.css.
Как сделать так чтобы приложение запускалось так же как и на других платформах?
https://github.com/Zakarayaev/QuizApplication
ссылка на GitHub
